# understanding 'lldb' backtace - app crashes when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, lldb

When I click on any button my app crashes. It throws a `lldb run time error`. I printed the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2aaf3, 0x000000018db701c0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1 2.1
frame #0: 0x000000018db701c0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x0000000181666bd4 CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 12
frame #2: 0x0000000182124720 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 256
frame #3: 0x00000001815b25ec CoreFoundation`-[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 248
frame #4: 0x00000001849eadd0 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1232
frame #5: 0x000000018492f878 UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
frame #6: 0x0000000184630488 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 88
frame #7: 0x00000001846303f4 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 32
frame #8: 0x00000001847dd868 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 704
frame #9: 0x00000001846e7f54 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 464
frame #10: 0x00000001846e7d24 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
frame #11: 0x00000001846e7ca4 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
frame #12: 0x000000018462aff8 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 348
frame #13: 0x000000018421c258 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
frame #14: 0x0000000184216e20 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 300
frame #15: 0x0000000184216cd8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
frame #16: 0x0000000184216560 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 280
frame #17: 0x0000000184216304 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 424
frame #18: 0x000000018420fc38 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
frame #19: 0x00000001816276a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
frame #20: 0x0000000181624930 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
frame #21: 0x0000000181624cbc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 764
frame #22: 0x0000000181565c20 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
frame #23: 0x000000018724dc0c GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
frame #24: 0x0000000184696fdc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1156
  * frame #25: 0x00000001001297a4 myapp`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd33ca8) + 116 at main.m:16
frame #26: 0x000000018e163aa0 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

What does it mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: update your answer with some relevant code

Comment: What is the error message. Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue a couple of times** and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post thatand an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: @Zaph I have an exception breakpoint but it is not getting called

Comment: @Zaph I posted an snapshot of what occurs on crash

Comment: This screenshot is not relevant..

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Sorry, Xcode is not telling me anything else, I have two exception breakpoints added but they are not being called

Comment: @zaph please see the further update of the code, the button is pressed, the log is printed, then crashes

Comment: Again, this code is not relevant..are you using xib/nib? we need to see what are you doing in IB..how you collegate the IBAction..etc.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi I am using story board, I have a tableview, when I click on the cell, it is pushed to the screen, which has a button, this button when pressed causes the crash. I add my button in interface builder, i then `ctrl+drag` the button to form the action.

Comment: So you have this button in a viewController, and you connected this button to an IBAction in your UIViewController subclass?

Comment: @MatteoGobbi yes you are correct

Comment: man..probably you made some error in IB..with these info we can't help you anymore..

Comment: @MatteoGobbi thank you for youre help, i apologise if there was any confusion caused.

Comment: No worries about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:]
```

because after this, is raised an `Exception`:

```
CoreFoundation`-[NSException raise] + 12
```

You are trying to **set a value for a key** in your object that **could not exists** or has some other problem.

P.S.: Update your answer with some relevant code so I can update my answer with more explanations.

Comment: Im not sure what code I can provide. I only click on a button that is not hooked to anything. Is there anything I can log to help you?

Comment: for example code of the viewController that you are trying to open or any other code relevant for what this button need to do..

Comment: Updated above, thanks for your conitued support. The log is printed when the button is pressed, but then crashes

Comment: This a problem between a nib and its implementation file. The most common cause is when an `IBOutlet` is renamed. The exception message will probably contain the exact problem.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you, I will look at this. Do you know what the numbers mean, eg `+ 12`

Comment: @Sulthan I deleted the file and started from scratch and it does look like an implementation file problem